# Booking Script and PHP Mail

Tags: php, email, ip, block

I have been trying to find a fix for this issue. The creators of the script are not very helpful. They told me to have receivers check the spam folder. I am mailing this to several test email addys on my own and HAVE checked SPAM/Junk.

I need the email confirmation to be sent to the customer. The problem is: the email only sends to GMail and AOL. Yahoo, hotmail, etc are not receiving the emails. The emails did not go into spam.

After contacting the host, they said my shared IP is likely blacklisted and I should use an external mail server or SMTP.

I know very little about PHP but am learning. I really appreciate the help.

//----Script tested to see if the server will work with GMail:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<mymail.gmail.com>';
$to = '<somemail.yahoo.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => '465',
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => 'mygmail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'myPASS'
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

//----ERROR: authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
//----Also Tried  $host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; AND different ports

//----Script in the functions php file in Script

```
function sendMail($email, $subject, $template,$serviceID, $data=null) {
    global $baseDir;
    $serviceSettings = getService($serviceID);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "From: 'MyName' <mymail@mydomain.net> \n";

 if ($data == null) {
    $message = $template;
 } else {
    $data ['{%server%}'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $$k = $v;
    }
    ob_start();
    include MAIN_PATH . "/emailTemplates/{$template}";
    $templ = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();     //$templ=file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$baseDir."emailTemplates/{$template}");
    $message = strtr($templ, $data);
}

//$message.="<br><br><a href='http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}'><img src='http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/images/logo_sm.png'></a>";

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

function sendMailFile($email, $subject, $template,$serviceID, $data=null,$file=null) {
global $baseDir;

$boundary = "--" . md5(uniqid(time()));
$EOL = PHP_EOL;

$serviceSettings = getService($serviceID);
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0;$EOL";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"$EOL";
$headers .= "From: 'MyName' <mymail@mydomain.net> $EOL";
$multipart = "--$boundary$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed$EOL";
$multipart .= $EOL;

if ($data == null) {
    $message = $template;
} else {
    $data ['{%server%}'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $$k = $v;
    }
    ob_start();
    include MAIN_PATH . "/emailTemplates/{$template}";
    $templ = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    //$templ=file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$baseDir."emailTemplates/{$template}");
    $message = strtr($templ, $data);
}

$multipart .=$message;
$name = "addToCalendar.ics";
$multipart .= "$EOL--$boundary$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$name\"$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"$EOL";
$multipart .= $EOL; // ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬-EDITED-Out-Encrypted-Code-On-Purpose-Ã‚Â»ÃƒÆ’Ã‚ÂÃƒâ€šÃ‚Â° 
$multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

$multipart .= "$EOL--$boundary--$EOL";


mail($email, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
}
```

Does anyone think I can get some kind of mail system to work with this script learning my limitations with the host?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain is that error 534 occurring all the time, or just when attempting email addresses other than @gmail. etc?

If it was all the time, I would ask if you had a firewall on your server, and is it blocking outgoing port 465?

If it is only creating an error when sending to other email addresses, then it is not an issue with the smtp host, but when Google is relaying the email to other mail servers round the world.

Comment: Is the "from" address the same as the Google account you are attempting to relay it through?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just tried with from and to @Gmail and received the same 534 error. Also, tested port 465 and it is open.

Comment: No, a different gmail address.

Comment: Also received an email from GMail warning me of unauthorized sign in attempt.

Comment: It's unlikely you can send email through the Google account if the address is not owned by the account. Was the from address just a different user, or a different domain as well?

Comment: just tried the same to and from @gmail...same error.

Comment: Set all emails to myaccount@gmail.com -authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: Have you logged in online to check there are no blocks on your account? Such as the captcha being triggered? And also do you have 2-Step authentication on your Google Account, if so you will need to create an application password for this script.

Comment: In my account under Unusual Activity: Application/device sign-in attempt (prevented) Unknown

Comment: Just to check, when I mentioned "myaccount@gmail.com" I meant put in place the Google Account address you're trying to relay it through.

Comment: Have you tried using this page...
https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: Just tried..same error. I just read something about adding Google SMTP App. Is this required?

Comment: Are you referring to Google Apps SMTP relay? https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: One other shot... Go to: https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1
In the list of signin, select the one which was blocked and contains the IP of your server.
Under Unusual activity click Change and Recognize the activity as yours.

Comment: Yes, am i understanding this correctly https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en you must now pay for google apps to use google's smtp server. If that is the case, do I have any other smtp mailing options with this script?

Comment: Marked as this is me..same thing.

Comment: You will only need to pay for Google Apps and use the GA SMTP relay if you're sending more than 2000 emails/day. Otherwise there should be no problems using the Gmail SMTP server with your script.

Comment: OK thanks, that's a relief. Well, it would be if i could get it to work!

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the gmail to work by creating a new gmail account. Your help is much appreciated. Sorry to keep this going but, any tips on plugging those gmail setting into the functions.php posted in my original question?

Comment: There's quite a lot of refactoring needed, for example the first test script you made uses the PEAR Mail Factory library, whereas the functions.php script uses custom preparation of the headers and body of the email. I would advise opening a separate question as the code is too extensive to write in comments.

Comment: If you want to mark this thread as answered and up vote it, I am happy to assist you via email with your additional question. alan[at]amormedia.co.uk